# Estimating Quantity $ p _2$ ​ from $ p _1 $​ with Mean Error Correction

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value, statistical-inference, means

If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two quantities, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are random variables representing them, and if the mean of the error is $\mu = E(P_1 - P_2)$, can the values of $p_2$ be estimated as $p_2 = p_1 - \mu$?

What are some books related to this?

Thank you.

Regards

Comment: Assuming they are independent, $\mu = E(P_1-P_2) = E(P_1)-E(P_2)$ so yes you can use that estimation

Comment: Yes, they are independent. By intuition, it seems possible. Can it be proven using linear approximation?